# Emacs ediff-buffers copy *all* diffs from a to b (or vice versa)

Tags: emacs

When using `ediff-buffers` is there a means to copy all diffs from a to b (or from b to a) with one key rather than having to go through every diff individually with the 'a' or 'b' key?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Is probably a silly question, is equivalent to just overwriting b with a. But there may be a use case if you'd manually done a few diffs and then realised all the rest were just a straight move from a to b. A bit like hitting ! In search and replace?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any provision for that in the ediff-copy-X-to-X functions. IOW, you'd need to do some elisp programming to add such a facility (assuming I haven't overlooked things of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboard macro to do it. Following is a keyboard pressing example.

1. <kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
2. <kbd>p</kbd> (this means jumping to the position before the first diff)
3. <kbd>F3</kbd> (start recording macro)
4. <kbd>n</kbd>
5. <kbd>a</kbd> (or <kbd>b</kbd>, depending on contents from which buffer you'd like to use)
6. <kbd>F4</kbd> (complete recording keyboard macro)
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> (for reptition number argument)
8. input a large enough number (larger than the total number of diffs)
9. <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Everything done!

If you save the keyboard macro, step 1 to step 6 needs to be done only once. But I think this works fine even without saving the macro. The problem of this solution is performance. If you have thousands of diffs, it might take quite a while to complete the operation.